# Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 40.83618432283402)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a problem with a leaflet, this error (Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 40.83618432283402)) is thrown when I click on the marker.
The most interesting thing is that the error is displayed with the coordinates of the center of the map (longitude without errors).
I reviewed a lot of similar errors, but in them the main solution was to fix the coordinates by which markers are drawn, in my case this did not help.
Below I will attach an error with the call stack, and how the markers are drawn.

I tried to change the coordinates of the marker position and cast them to the latlng type, but there was no noticeable difference. Maybe it's not the markers? But why then the error is thrown when the marker is clicked?

[call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahtDe.png)

```
<MarkerClusterGroup
                key={Date.now()}
                iconCreateFunction={createClusterCustomIcon1}
                spiderfyDistanceMultiplier={3}
                maxClusterRadius={95}
                singleMarkerMode={false}
                animated={false}
            >
                {context.singleDay && points.map((nat, index) => (
                    (context.min_datetime <= Date.parse(nat.datetime) && Date.parse(nat.datetime) <= context.max_datetime) &&
                    <Marker icon={GetIcon(10, 10, nat.temperature)}
                            key={index}
                            position={new L.LatLng(nat.longitude,nat.latitude)}
                    >
                        <Popup closeButton={false} key={index}>
                            Координаты: {nat.latitude}, {nat.longitude}
                            <br/>
                            Температура: {nat.temperature}
                            <br/>
                            Время: {nat.datetime}

                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                ))}
                {context.daysInRange && points.map((nat, index) => (
                    <Marker icon={GetIcon(10, 10, nat.temperature)}
                            key={index}
                            position={new L.LatLng(nat.longitude, nat.latitude)}
                            updateWhenZooming={false}
                            updateWhenIdle={true}
                    >
                        <Popup closeButton={false} key={index}>
                            Координаты: {nat.latitude}, {nat.longitude}
                            <br/>
                            Температура: {nat.temperature}
                            <br/>
                            Время: {nat.datetime}
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                ))}
            </MarkerClusterGroup>
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: what is `L.LatLng`, docs page? the function name suggests lat/lon not lon/lat

Comment: @Lawrence, Yes, you are right, but I did this because the received latitude and longitude are initially mixed up in places. I already checked it, and the only thing it affects is the location of the markers)